# Woocommerce Floating Bar has additional Margin-Top

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I **Enabled** the **Floating-Bar** in Single Product in Woocommerce, it's working fine using the default Header. However, I created a custom header and I noticed that the Floating-Bar has now additional `margin-top` of `74px` same with the height of the Header and another `Top` with the current `off-set` of the Header.

I tried to override the `css` of `owp-floating-bar` but nothings happen.

```
.owp-floating-bar{
 margin-top: 0px !important;
}
```

There is also no option for margin in customization.

Answer (score 0):

You've just missed the class `show`.

Assuming the `Floating-Bar` is `Enabled`. Once you are in a Single-Product page,  the floating-bar will be shown once you scroll-down, it happens by adding the class `show` on the class `owp-floating-bar`.

To override the `margin-top`:

```
.owp-floating-bar.show{
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Now you do. You managed to get the class `owp-floating-bar` but did not notice the `show`.